# CSS grid not rendering video as expected in Edge/Chrome

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

I have a list of some items in a db with a column and row span. I want to then display these within a webpage.
My initial thought was to use Bootstrap, but I think that might be overcomplicating what I am trying to achieve.

I have been testing the grid CSS with a video element and it seems to resize the video within the grid within Firefox. In Chrome and Edge however the video is resized to fill the area, which can make it much larger.

**My test set up:**
In the CSS I have configured a 4 x 4 grid to put the video elements into.
I have CSS to size the videos as:

1 small video on the top right (1 X 1).
1 long video on the top (3 X 1).
2 equal sized video on the bottom.

This should produce a video with little border, then a long video at the top (a large width border).
2 videos at the bottom with a small border to fit.

My code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var videos = $('.video');
  for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var video = videos[i];
    PlayHlsVideo(video);

  }
});

function PlayHlsVideo(videoItem) {
  var videoSrc = 'https://multiplatform-f.akamaihd.net/i/multi/will/bunny/big_buck_bunny_,640x360_400,640x360_700,640x360_1000,950x540_1500,.f4v.csmil/master.m3u8';
  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();

    var config = {
      testBandwidth: false,
      abrEwmaDefaultEstimate: 1000000,
      startLevel: -1
    }

    var hls = new Hls(config);

    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);

    if (hls.loadSource != null) {
      hls.attachMedia(videoItem);

      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
        //required for auto-play but off on currently. may need to be on for live stream.
        //video.muted = 'muted';
        videoItem.play();
      });
    }
  }

  // HLS.js is not supported on platforms that do not have Media Source
  // Extensions (MSE) enabled.
  //
  // When the browser has built-in HLS support (check using `canPlayType`),
  // we can provide an HLS manifest (i.e. .m3u8 URL) directly to the video
  // element through the `src` property. This is using the built-in support
  // of the plain video element, without using HLS.js.
  //
  // Note: it would be more normal to wait on the 'canplay' event below however
  // on Safari (where you are most likely to find built-in HLS support) the
  // video.src URL must be on the user-driven white-list before a 'canplay'
  // event will be emitted; the last video event that can be reliably
  // listened-for when the URL is not on the white-list is 'loadedmetadata'.
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = videoSrc;
  }
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  align-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}

.video-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.item4 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-3 & jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Body -->
<div class="grid-container">
  <video id="video_1" class="item1 video video-wrap"></video>
  <video id="video_2" class="item2 video video-wrap"></video>
  <video id="video_3" class="item3 video video-wrap"></video>
  <video id="video_4" class="item4 video video-wrap"></video>
</div>
```

This is how it looks in Firefox (as expected):

[image: Firefox]

This is how it looks in Chrome/Edge (not scaled correctly):

[image: Edge]

I have tried resizing the width and height of the video with 100% and auto. I can't seem to get it to size the video as expected in Edge.

Additionally if it would be easier/make more sense to do it another way such as Bootstrap. I would be happy to do that.

My only caveat is that the data in the db might have 1 small video in the middle. Such as an item at column 2 and 3 and row 2 and 3 so a big border on the outside, or any combination of size and layout theoretically.

Comment: Hi, please use a Stacksnippet `<>` or `Ctrl+M` the next time you post code. That stacksnippet is runnable and show the output of your code directly. Also you can include images directly instead of just linking them. I edited your question and did the formatting for you.

Comment: No problem I'll make sure to do that in future. Thanks for editing the question for me, much appreciated.

Comment: Something I find helpful when working with CSS grids is Edge's DevTools' Layout tab, where it gives the option to show information about track sizes and gives an overlay of the grid lines. Then you can you can see how your elements fit in those tracks. I would consider using an image backup for the video source so that something is shown if the user does not have HLS support.